# Mysql + Update to table (same time) with Join

Tags: mysql

I believe this is possible but I haven't done it before.

I need to update 2 tables and I want to use one MySQL command. I also have a join field.

```
 UPDATE static_site_articles SET domainname='a',language='b',url='domain',toptext='c',bottomtext='d' WHERE id='10;

 UPDATE static_site_articles_meta SET url='domain',title='e',description='f',keywords='g';
```

They join with the url='domain'.

How can I construct this into a single UPDATE command line?

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

thx

Comment: I thikn in the second case, you're doing an INSERT and not update.

Comment: heads up..your second query does'nt have `where` condition..

Comment: Check out this example -> http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0140__Insert-Update-Delete/Updatetwotablesinoneupdatestatement.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```